# @JoinFetch not doing anything (EclipseLink)

Tags: java, jpa, left-join, eclipselink

I have an entity Base, with a many-to-one relationship to an entity Nested. I want to order a query by the Nested.name, where name can be null. Even if name is null I want the query to return this row. So I'm trying to make EclipseLink generate queries that LEFT JOINs these together, instead of selecting from both tables.

I have annotated the relationship between Base and Nested with the @JoinFetch annotation as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "BASE_ID")
@JoinFetch(value = JoinFetchType.OUTER)
private Nested nested;
```

However, this does not seem to affect the queries generated by EclipseLink in any way at all. The actual generated query is

```
SELECT ... FROM BASE t0, NESTED t1 WHERE (t1.ID = t0.BASE_ID) ORDER BY t1.NAME ASC...
```

while I expect something along the lines of

```
SELECT ... FROM BASE t0 LEFT JOIN NESTED t1 ON (t1.ID = t0.BASE_ID) ORDER BY t1.NAME ASC...
```

I am using the JPA 2.0 Criteria API to build and execute queries. Even if I explicitly build a joined query using the criteria API the resulting query will look like the first one, without joins. Explicitly joining when building the query seems to work fine with Hibernate, but has no effect on the resulting query in EclipseLink.

I'm probably missing something basic here, so any tips are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is in your orderBy (which is not using an outer join so nullifies the fetch's outer join).

How are you setting the order by?  Are you using an outer join for it?

Comment: Basically what the code does is `Join<Object, Object> join = queryRoot.join("nested", JoinType.LEFT);
query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(join.get("name")));`

Comment: The problem was that I had first done `queryRoot.get("nested")`and then `queryRoot.join...`, which apparently caused the first "get" to specify the join to be an INNER join. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!